# system strucking when brightness symboll came

Tags: display

my system is strucking, when the brightness symboll came top off the screen on right side,   and it is blinking,then that time the system will struck....I am completely new to ubuntu,so please help me.
Thank You Sir.

Comment: I used to have a similar problem with older Ubuntu releases with a MSI Wind laptop - due to a bug the system was constantly changing display brightness up and down, with brightness notification popup showing constantly; often after resuming from suspend. As I remember the problem has been fixed in newer releases of Ubuntu; I also remember there were some work-arounds, but I don't remember the details. What's your Ubuntu version and laptop model?

Comment: And here's the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal-info/+bug/415023 - seems that for MSI Wind laptop the solution was to update BIOS.

Comment: @Sergey how can i do that ? how to update the BIOS ?

Comment: Have a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal-info/+bug/415023/comments/343 - I haven't tried to follow those steps, and I don't have the laptop anymore, but that's where I would start if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've an athec lug netbook ("a MSI clone") and also have the blinking brightness problem after upgrading my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS.
Here you have a workaround that is working fine for me:

```
sudo chmod u-w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

And then I can adjust the brightness by keyboard (Fn+...)